# lightdm port to listen if it is up

Tags: lightdm

I am making an ansible check to see if lightdm is up before continuing a task in my playbook.

Is there a port number that lightdm creates once it's up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: *"Check to see if lightdm is up before continuing a task"*

A: It's possible to use [service_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_facts_module.html) and select attributes of a particular service. For example the playbook

```
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    my_service: 'lightdm.service'

  tasks:
    - service_facts:
    - set_fact:
        my_state: "{{ services|
                      dict2items|
                      selectattr('key', 'match', my_service)|
                      map(attribute='value.state')|
                      list|
                      first }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_service }} is {{ my_state }}"
```

gives

```
"msg": "lightdm.service is running"
```

Answer (score 1):

No. `lightdm` is a display manager, designed to run over X. 
It is not supposed to open network port...